# data visualization with missing dates

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, data-visualization

I have 2 graphs (shown below). They show average wait times by day. The time span is from Aug 1 to October 30, but we are missing all of September.

I think these graphs are misleading, but wasn't sure what the "best practice" was in dealing with this. Should I just split graphs in 2? One for August and one for October?

Another possibility would be to add a zero for all September dates?

[image][image]

Comment: The bottom one does not seem misleading to me. Thre are clearly no points in September.  You could superimpose the points on the top one (and possibly the bottom one too) so that its clear that there are no points in September.  Another possibility which could be used alternatively or in addition to this is to add a `geom_rug()` which will display the location of the points along the bottom.

Comment: Don't set the September dates to 0, set them to NA. That will be much clearer.

Comment: Best practice with respect to what? Is this a user-experience question?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about scientific publishing, not programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be best if you could somehow avoid plotting data that don't exist. Sometimes it gives a wrong impression. I personally disagree with @g-grothendieck's comment about the second plot, however only from an aesthetic perspective. There are indeed no points in September, but the line is slightly misleading.

To avoid plotting points in a chart you should set them as `NA`. `ggplot` would then disregard them. An example of how you could achieve it is below:

```
library(ggplot2)
# The 4 lines below create your data.frame
# This is the vector of all your dates
x=seq(from=as.Date('2014-08-01'),to=as.Date('2014-10-30'),by='1 day')

# this is your original data.frame
df=data.frame(DAY=x, P1=runif(length(x)), P2=runif(length(x)), P3=runif(length(x)))
# and there are no lines inside this date-range
df<-df[df$DAY<='2014-08-29' | df$DAY>='2014-09-28',]

#If you create another data.frame with a left join across al dates, you would get NAs in the missing dates.
df.2<-merge(data.frame(DAY=x),df, by='DAY',all.x=TRUE)
ggplot(df.2,aes(DAY,P1))+geom_line()
```

Plotting, would have this effect:

[image]

It is not necessarily the best way to do it, but I think it is cleaner. No data, means no data points.

Thanks

Comment: Agree completely.  If you have a gap in the data, show it. @crock1255 :  you can get in to trouble with anything else, especially if you smooth the data as in your first figure (any smoothing should be done piecewise)

Comment: This is such a great answer. Thank you!